# Webpack not assigning value to environment variable

Tags: javascript, webpack, environment-variables, config

I want to make my url private.

In my `Webpack.config.js` I declared a few environment variables and required `dotenv-webpack`.

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
    'NODE_ENV',
    'MY_URL'
  ]),
  new Dotenv({
    path: './.env', // Path to .env file (this is the default)
    safe: false // load .env.example (defaults to "false" which does not use dotenv-safe)
  })
]
```

Then I created a `.env` and added `MY_URL=http://my.secret.url`

But when I log `process.env.MY_URL` it is `undefined`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can share the way that works for me. I move all my environment variables to config.js and in package.json I set my current environment(local or prod) and I can use `npm run local` or `npm run prod`

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "workshop_butler_widget",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Workshopbutler widget",
  "author": "http://workshopbutler.com",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    ....
  },
  "scripts": {
    "local": "NODE_ENV=local webpack-dev-server",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=prod webpack-dev-server"
  }
}
```

config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  local: {
    url: 'http://local'
  },
  prod: {
    url: 'http://prod'
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const configs  = require('./config.js');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const current = (env === "local")? configs.local: configs.prod; 


...

plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env),
   'MY_URL': JSON.stringify(current.url)
  })
]
```

or you can read .env file directly in webpack.config.js through 'fs' npm package